# How to upload RAR, CSV, DOC, DOCX, XLS and XLSX files to a Symfony2 application

Tags: php, excel, symfony, csv, file-upload

I created an **Entity** with the atribute `file` like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Archivo {
    /**
     * @var File
     *
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "6M",
     *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf",
     *                    "application/x-rar-compressed","application/octet-stream", "application/zip"},
     *     maxSizeMessage = "Symfony: File too big!",
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Symfony: Invalid file type!" 
     * )
     */
     protected $file;
}
```

I use this method to store the file:

```
public function upload($file, $path) {
    if (null === $file) {
        return;
    }
    $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $file->move(
            $path, $name
    );
    unset($file);
}
```

And this is my **Form** :

```
class ArchivoType extends AbstractType {

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('file', 'file')

    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'SisEvo\UploadBundle\Entity\Archivo'
    ));
}
```

}

When I submit the form with a RAR file, the warning `Symfony: Invalid file type!` is shown. How can I let to upload RAR, CSV,  DOC, DOCX, XLS and XLSX files?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you RAR file has the 'application/x-rar-compressed' MIME Type ? It can also be some deprecated old MIME Type like 'vnd.rar'

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681424/how-to-create-a-csv-file-using-php-and-upload-it?rq=1

Comment: Sorry @MarcGiroux , I have different problem. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question; as @Alsatian said, my RAR is not an 'application/x-rar-compressed'.
I used this [website](http://mime.ritey.com/) to check the MIME Type of my RAR file. I discovered that my RAR file is  "application/x-rar".

Thank you for your time!